# how to display time from db table into drop downlist yii2?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

this is my form field for dropdown list `Time`

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'Time')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
            'data' => ArrayHelper::map(Schedule::find()->where(['username' => 'cust_id', 'day'=>'Day_cust','availability'=>'available'])->all(),'time','time'),
            'language' => 'en',
            'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select available time ...'],
            'pluginOptions' => [
            'allowClear' => true
            ],
        ]);
        ?>
```

`Day_cust` and `cust_id` is taken from the previous text input in the same form which is field by the user.

I have tried the above code but it failed to display the time available.

this is my model for schedule

```
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'schedule_id' => 'Schedule ID',
        'username' => 'Username',
        'day' => 'Day',
        'time' => 'Time',
        'availability' => 'Availability',
    ];
}
```

what I want is I want to display on the drop-down list for `time` the time input in the database with the availability `available` based on `cust_id` and `day` insert by the user in the field.

how should I do it?

if anyone wonder why i dont use dependent dropdownlist is because the cust_id is using text input same goes with the day. i didnt use the ddl for both of them.

Comment: thats quiet a clean model with a single function only, and depdrop does not have a limitation to be dependent on dropdowns only it just needs an input selector and it will trigger the depdrop as soon as the text input  changes

Answer (score 0):

In your `ArrayHelper::map()`, make sure you have used correct database field values.

Your database field contains `time` not `Time`, So `ArrayHelper` should be like,

```
ArrayHelper::map(Schedule::find()->where(['username' => 'cust_id', 'day'=>'Day_cust','availability'=>'available'])->all(),'time','time')
```

Comment: yaa but still it didnt prompt what i need. i need to display all the time which have the availability is "available" based on the username and day selected

Comment: If you are trying to implement dependent dropdown list then you should make use of ajax request. By selecting User from the previous Dropdown list, you need to make a request to the server and fetch data for that User accordingly.